# Date accessed in ConTeXt bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, context

I’m looking at switching from LaTeX to ConTeXt, with the only piece left being the bibliography. In the past I used BibLaTeX, which made use of the `urldate` field of the `@online` entry category. [ConTeXt’s bibliography system](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Bibliography_mkiv) doesn’t support `@online`, so I used `@electronic` instead. After doing some digging through [the Publications manual](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf) I found out that there is no `urldate` or equivalent field for any entry category.

Is there a non-hacky way (perhaps using Librarian?) to display access dates in the bibliography?

Thanks.

Comment: The bibliography system is pretty much under development, you might want to ask your question on the mailing list.

Comment: Last time I checked there was no easy way to add custom fields to the bibliography.  The Lua code that is responsible for this is well encapsulated and not readily accessible from outside.